# creating war file using maven-ear-plugin and defining it in one pom.xml

Tags: maven, war

I am at the starter level of the maven usage. I hope I can explain my problem clearly, I want to create an ear file which contains war file inside it. And I planned to use  to create a war file from the start. Also I want to do it in my pom.xml at my project and there is only one pom.xml, here is the problem;

1. Can I create ear file and which contains this war that I created at the same time in one pom.xml file?
2. when I try to create war file in webmodule tag, here is the problem that I encounter " Artifact[war:denem.denem:denem] is not a dependency of the project." I understood so that's why I added dependency for this file in the same pom.xml but this time I encountered that problem

(By the way my command to build this pom is "mvn clean package" )

"1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact:

```
com.denem.denem:com.denem.de2:ear:v0.1"
```

It tries to find this war file but I want to create it not to find it. Here the code in my pom.xml file;

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>denem.denem</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.denem.denem</artifactId>
    <version>v0.1</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>denem.denem</groupId>
<artifactId>com.denem.de2</artifactId>
<version>v0.1</version>

<packaging>ear</packaging>

<properties>
    <cxf.version>2.2.5</cxf.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>denem.denem</groupId>
        <artifactId>denem</artifactId>
        <version>v0.1</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>edu</finalName>
                <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                <modules>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>denem.denem</groupId>
                        <artifactId>denem</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/WebContent</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </modules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

I guess I am doing lots of things wrong. But If you can help me I will be glad. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a modular project.
Create:

1. a parent project of type "pom";
2. a child project of type "war";
3. if needed, child projects of type "ejb";
4. if needed, child projects of type "jar" (common libraries);
5. one project of type "ear", that has all of the above as dependencies.

In the latter you need to configure the ear plugin putting all the modules that you need.